# what are aggregated columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

What are aggregated columns and non-aggregated columns? I have read the MySQL Handling of `GROUP BY` and am confused. I do not know what 'aggregated columns' mean. Does anybody know?

MySQL Handling of `GROUP BY` [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: An aggregate function performs a calculation on a set of values, and returns a single value.

Comment: An aggregated column is the result of passing a set of its values to an aggregate function. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Prefect explanation http://spatial-analyst.net/ILWIS/htm/ilwismen/aggregate_column.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions like `SUM`, `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `COUNT` calculate data over a group of records and return aggregated results.

E.g.

`` SELECT SUM(`salary`) FROM `employees`; ``

Returns 1 row with the total salary when

`` SELECT `salary` FROM `employees`; ``

Returns multiple rows with the salary per employee.

Lets say you want the average salary per gender:

`` SELECT `gender`, AVG(`salary`) FROM `employees` GROUP BY `gender`; ``

Query 1 & 3 contain aggregated columns: `` SUM(`salary`) `` AND `` AVG(`salary`) ``

Answer (score 1):

`SUM`, `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc all are [aggregate functions](http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions/) which create a column as a result of combining multiple rows.

Aggregated columns are columns returned as a result of applying aggregate function ( `SUM`, `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`)